# Php calculete the cost for each day passed

Tags: php, mysql

```
  $1date =$row['Date1'];
     $2date = $row['Date2'];
       $datediff = $1date - $2date;
echo $datediff;
```

I want to count the days between and put into a table the result(10 dollars for each day passed)

Comment: In which format are the dates stored?

Comment: the dates are stores into mysql as dates

Comment: If you're working with mysql, then do it directly in sql, not in php ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// convert to unix timestamp
$1date = strtotime($row['Date1']);
$2date = strtotime($row['Date2']);

// 86400 seconds in a day
// floor to round down, change to ceil to round up
$datediff = floor(($1date - $2date) / 86400);

$cost = $days * 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in MySQL then work it into a variable. Do the initial call

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF('Date1','Date2');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$days = date_diff(date_create($row['Date1']), date_create($row['Date2']))->format('%a');
$cost = $days * 10;
```

Comment: i get an error at the first line

Comment: whats the error message?

Comment: Sorry i missed off a closing bracket before the ->format

Comment: i've edited to include it, could you try it again?